# Proof of divergence of two complex series

Tags: limits, divergent-series

My task is to check, when the following series are convergent:
$$ $$ a) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} z^n$
$$ $$
B) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{n^n} z^n$
$$ $$ where $z$ is a complex number. Ok, in both cases I computed the radius of convegence. In a) I got $R=\frac{1}{4}$ and in b) I got $R=e$. Those answers are correct, as my book says. But I don't know what happens on the boundary, I mean in first case for $z=\frac{1}{4}$ and in the second for $z=e$. Wolfram says that in both cases it diverges, first one from the comparison test (but compare to what?) and the second one because $\lim \frac{n!}{n^n} e^n = \infty$ (Why?). How to prove it? I really tried, got so frustrated, because it should be easy, but I can't prove divergence of those series... Can you help?

---

Edit: after hint with Stirling formula, I've got the second one (b) ). Help still needed in a). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you heard of Stirling's formula (or Stirling's approximation, as it also is frequently dubbed)?

Comment: The boundary is more than just $z=\frac{1}{4}$, it's all the complex numbers $z$ such that $|z|= \frac{1}{4}$. Convergence or divergence at one point on the boundary doesn't guarantee convergence or divergence along the rest of the boundary, in general.

Comment: Daniel Fischer, thanks! That was helpful, I got the second one already, I'll edit my post in a minute.

Comment: TBrendle, yes, true, but if it diverges for z=1/4, it will diverge for all z such that |z| = 1/4.

Comment: @Anne are you sure? Try z=-1/4. I was a little surprised when you wrote it should be easy… it's not easy to figure out what happens on the boundary, in general.

Comment: No @Anne: if it diverges for $\;z=\frac14\;$ it does *not* mean it'll diverge for all the complex s.t. $\;|z|=\frac14\;$ ...

Comment: Ah, ok, you're right of course... Sorry. So is there any method to check it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, you seem to be working under an assumption that if the series has radius of convergence $r$, then its convergence or divergence along the entire boundary can be determined by its convergence or divergence at the point $z=r$. This is false.

It's easy to see, for example, that for series of the form 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$$
with the $a_n>0$ decreasing monotonically from some $n$ on,  and with radius of convergence $0<r<1$,
we must always have convergence at $z=-r$ by the alternating series test.

Don't beat yourself up. When you say "it should be easy" you are wrong. The convergence of a power series along the boundary of its radius of convergence is a complicated question and there are even some open questions remaining for research mathematicians. Are you absolutely sure you have to determine behavior at boundary?

While this isn't quite an answer, hopefully it should make you feel better!

Edit:

An example often given: The series 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n
$$
has radius of convergence $r=1$ but diverges at every point along its boundary, but its derivative
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} z^n
$$
has the same radius of convergence $r=1$ but diverges at $z=1$ and converges at every other point on the boundary.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) no, it was just my own interpretation of the task, and because it is my first attempt to find where complex series diverge, I thought it's not gonna be that hard. But I guess it was enough to find the radius.